# How are codes assigned value in Shannon Fano Coding?

Tags: coding-theory

I am trying to understand how Shannon Fano Codes are being assigned values in the following example. Please help me understand it.
[image]

Comment: It might be better if you could explain what you don't understand. Did you read the paragraph above?  The list is divided into "two groups of as nearly equal probabilities as possible". It looks as though they put $a$ into one group and $b-h$ in the other group.  Each symbol in the first group ($a$) is assigned a 0 as the first bit, so $a$ gets a 0 as its first bit. The others get a 1 as their first bit.

Comment: So I, II, III, IV and V are groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better if you could explain what you don't understand. Did you read the paragraph above?

The list is divided into "two groups of as nearly equal probabilities as possible". It looks as though they put $a$ into one group and $b-h$ in the other group.  Each symbol in the first group ($a$) is assigned a 0 as the first bit, so $a$ gets a 0 as its first bit. The others get a 1 as their first bit. the result is column I of the table

Then the second group is further divided, into $c,e$ and $b,d,f,g,h$. The items in the first group get an additional 0 on their codes; the items in the second group get an additional 1. This is column II of the table.